# Rice–Shapiro theorem example

Tags: computability

[Rice-Shapiro](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/67722/rice-shapiro-theorem) theorem is:

> Let $Γ$ be a set of computable functions such that the set $R_Γ$ is recursively enumerable. We have $f ∈ Γ$ if and only if there exists a finite function $θ ∈ Γ$ such that $θ ⊆ f$.

If $Γ$ is singleton set, for example $Γ = \lbrace ϕ_{10}\rbrace$ then $R_Γ = \lbrace 10 \rbrace$ and is recursively enumerable, but $Γ$ does not satisfy:

$f ∈ Γ$ if and only if there exists a finite function $θ ∈ Γ$ such that $θ ⊆ f$.

Where I have made a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flaw is that $R_\Gamma$ includes not just the natural number $10$, but any natural number which gives rise to the same partial recursive function. It will be infinite, and not recursively enumerable.

In general, for any partial recursive function $f$ you can think of, there will be many Godel numbers which describe it. In other words, many partial recursive function *descriptions* result in the same actual *function*. If you are more familiar with Turing machines, there will always be many different Turing machines which compute the same abstract function or language.

**In summary:** $\Gamma$ is any set of functions. However, $R_\Gamma$ is the set of natural numbers which *encode* that function. In your case, for $\Gamma = \{\phi_{10}\}$, $R_\Gamma$ is the set of natural numbers which encode the same function as $10$, and this set is not recursively enumerable.

Comment: I think you are right, but can you describe for example halting problem ,as a RE set, by this theorem? I mean for halting problem I can not construct $\Gamma$...

Comment: @Hossein It is not true that *any* RE set is equal to $R_\Gamma$ for some $\Gamma$. For the halting problem, though, you can do it. Take $\Gamma$ to be the set of functions which are defined on input $0$. Then $R_\Gamma$ is the set of descriptions of such functions, which is the set of descriptions (programs) which halt on input $0$.

Comment: You can also see that the theorem holds for thtis $\Gamma$. We have that $f \in \Gamma$ if and only if $f(0)$ is defined, so equivalently, $f \in \Gamma$ if and only if the function just sending $0$ to $a$ is a subset of $f$ for some $a \in \mathbb{N}$.